# Vaadin 8 change global font programatically

Tags: java, css, vaadin, font-size, vaadin8

I have a user preference window which allows user to select the fontsize and on apply of the window (with a click button) all the component in the root UI and children get new fontsize.

I have tried all solutions available to handle global font setting change using scss file. However, only the elements directly under the root UI font is changed but children like Tree Elements and Grid Row font still remains the same.

Here is link to similar question, which works partially.
https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/10962145

Solution 1 : Use **styles.scss** file to configure as below

```
@import "mytheme.scss";
@import "addons.scss";
@import "mythememedium.scss";
@import "mythemelarge.scss";

.mytheme {
  @include addons;
  @include mytheme;
}

.mytheme-small{
   $v-font-size: 13px;
  @include mytheme;
}

.mytheme-medium{
   $v-font-size: 16px;
  @include mythememedium;
}

.mytheme-large{
   $v-font-size: 17px;
  @include addons;
  @include mythemelarge;
}
```

**UserPreferenceWindow.java**

```
apply.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
@Override
public void buttonClick(Button.ClickEvent event) {
       String fontSize = (String) fontSizeCmb.getValue();
       String styleName = UI.getCurrent().getStyleName();
       if (fontSize.equals("MEDIUM")) {
            UI.getCurrent().addStyleName("abstheme-medium");
            UI.getCurrent().removeStyleName(styleName);
        } else if (fontSize.equals("LARGE")) {
            UI.getCurrent().addStyleName("abstheme-large");
            UI.getCurrent().removeStyleName(styleName);
        } else {
            UI.getCurrent().addStyleName("abstheme-small");
            UI.getCurrent().removeStyleName(styleName);
        }
     }
});
```

**mythemelarge.scss**

```
.v-tree8 {
  .v-tree8-scroller, .v-tree8-scroller-horizontal { }
  .v-tree8-tablewrapper {
    .v-tree8-body {
      .v-tree8-row,
      .v-tree8-stripe,
      .v-tree8-row-focused,
      .v-tree8-row-has-data {
        .v-tree8-expander, expanded {}
        .v-tree8-cell-content {font-size: 17px;  color: black !important;}
      }
    }
  }
}
}

.mygrid .v-grid-body .v-grid-cell {  
    font-size: 17px;       // adjust to your needs
}
```

Any pointers on how to handle this??

TIA.

Comment: I can imagine one solution: Build several themes, for small, medium, large font and switch themes to adapt the font size. But this is kind of bad workaround.

Comment: Why not let the web browser do the work of larger fonts? For example, `View` > `Zoom In` in Safari.

Comment: @SteffenHarbich : this is my solution currently, which is a workaround. Any other better solution your are aware?

Comment: No, I am using Vaadin 10 now which is easier in that case.